# How to implement a DataView in Cocoa?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, view, interface-builder, nsview

What would be the best way to implement (using Cocoa) a DataView as presented in this [example](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.0.1/examples/view/data-view.html):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. IKImageBrowserView

The image below is taken directly from Apple's [Image Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageKitProgrammingGuide/ImageBrowser/ImageBrowser.html) documentation and does exactly what you need.

[image: IKImageBrowserView]

### 2. NSCollectionView

[NSCollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCollectionView_Class/index.html) is more general because you are not restricted to just presenting images; you can present a collection of any NSView subclass you like. Try this if you need more customisation. For example, you could have a NSImageView, NSTextField and NSButton in your subclass if you needed to have a more complex user interface.